# Using Backbone.Collection for a Paginated List?

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, pagination

I'm wondering if I should be using a Backbone.Collection called `ExerciseList` for my exercises page, which displays `Exercise`s filtered by various properties. Each `Exercise` is rendered with an `ExerciseRowView`. So, would an `ExerciseList` and `ExerciseListView` be feasible/useful in this sort of situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would work just fine, you're definitely headed in the right direction. You'll have to create a pagination method on the collection.

Here's a great pagination component: https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator

Have a look at Addy Osmani's (the plugin author) article on Backbone pagination here:
http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/

Should get you the rest of the way there.