# Having trouble logically setting up a page system for Backbone

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, mvvm

So I am getting a response from the server with the following array

```
[
   [{title: "abc", author: "james"}, {title: "bcd", author: "jack"}],
   [{title: "cde", author: "john"}, {title: "def", author: "jake"}], 
   [{title: "xyz", author: "frank"}]
]
```

Now with Backbone I am trying to take this response and create pages, 1 for each sub-array and then on each page it should show the info within each sub-array.

I was using request.js to define and separate the files, and this is my take on the models, views, and collections but for some reason I cannot understand what is the right approach because the information comes back in a collection.

I was going to create a view for each sub-array's object. so for the objects I will display a

```
<td> "abc" </td>
<td> "james" </td>
```

that would be in a collection with a fetch calling the data then looping through each data and showing the amount of objects per page (2 in this example)

then writing a function that if the next page === 1 then print out the second sub-array, etc...

then similarly a view for the pages with the same concept, depending on the route:pageid show each page with a next and prev button that takes you to current -1 or current +1 of the pageid... but In the way I am visioning this I do not see a place for a model... does that make sense or if there is a better way to do all this with the response from the server please share.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`Backbone.Collection` is tied to the `Array` concept. It is meant to be an array of objects, not an array of arrays of objects. Your problem will be better solved by using a single collection (that would abstract the data more cleanly) and pagination.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217073/using-backbone-collection-for-a-paginated-list) for further directions.

Comment: Ok so my server is sending back the data to the url /music, how do I go about .fetch() -ing the data and then pulling it apart in the single collection/view... I am unsure about how I can manipulate the data exactly after .fetch() or how it works.